# Let's get critical: Feb 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Network Engineering Stack Exchange](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [BGP Graceful-restart Initialization Flag](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14935/bgp-graceful-restart-initialization-flag)

**Net Score: 11** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [static link aggregation](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14671/static-link-aggregation)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Why is the IP layer aware of higher layers in the network stack?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14841/why-is-the-ip-layer-aware-of-higher-layers-in-the-network-stack)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Cisco Fiber switch perform at 100/1000](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14738/cisco-fiber-switch-perform-at-100-1000)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How do I restrict a user for certain commands on Cisco IOS](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14570/how-do-i-restrict-a-user-for-certain-commands-on-cisco-ios)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Why is this a network if all host bits are zeros?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14956/why-is-this-a-network-if-all-host-bits-are-zeros)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How do wi-fi spots display their name?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14908/how-do-wi-fi-spots-display-their-name)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Why is ISP link address different than my assigned IP addresses?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14974/why-is-isp-link-address-different-than-my-assigned-ip-addresses)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Neighbor Discovery Protocol](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14780/neighbor-discovery-protocol)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [How can I connect to different subnet within site-to-site vpn configuration](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14695/how-can-i-connect-to-different-subnet-within-site-to-site-vpn-configuration)

**Net Score: -9** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 9)

---